# I have a working solution for reading and writing Excel files. But I am trying to figure out how to send an object from/to the same files

Tags: post

I have been trying to send an object over to another file.  I have the solution for writing to an excel file by pushing a button on the frontend, and the file gets written on the backend.

However, I am tring to do something similar, only I want to be able to send an object that would be contained on the button page, over the file (post.controllers).  But anything I try doesn't work.

This is something that I have tried.

```
const objectTransfer = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
fetch("http://localhost:3000/storedReceivingObject", {
method: 'POST',
body: JSON.stringify(storedReceivingObject),
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json',
},
}
)}
```

and this is just taking an object from the same file, such as

```
var storedReceivingContainerOne = 1;
var storedReceivingContainerTwo = 2;
var storedReceivingContainerThree = 3;
var storedReceivingContainerFour = 4;
var storedReceivingContainerFive = 5;
var storedReceivingContainerSix = 6;




var storedReceivingObjectTest = {
    1:storedReceivingContainerOne,
    2:storedReceivingContainerTwo,
    3:storedReceivingContainerThree,
    4:storedReceivingContainerFour,
    5:storedReceivingContainerFive,
    6:storedReceivingContainerSix,
}
```

Here is the code that works for writing to the files.  There are a few files.

```
// index.html 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" conTent="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" conTent="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
                
<button class="btnOverWriteAccess" 
onclick="btnOverWrite()">Overwrite</button>

</div>

</body>
<script src="./Frontend/buttonPage.js"></script>



// buttonPage.js 

var storedReceivingObject = {
1:'One',
2:'Two',
3:'Three'
}


let btnOverWriteAccess = 
document.querySelector('.btnOverWriteAccess');

function btnOverWrite(){
fetch("http://localhost:3000/posts", {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json',
},
})
}



// post.js / controllers

const http = require('http');

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

var html = "";

global.document = new JSDOM(html).window.document;

exports.createPost = (req, res, _) => {

const reader = require('xlsx')

const file = reader.readFile('../project3Temp.xlsx')

let data = []

const sheets = file.SheetNames

for(let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++)
{
const temp = reader.utils.sheet_to_json(
file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[i]])
temp.forEach((res) => {
data.push(res)
})
}

console.log(data)

let XLSX = require('xlsx')

let excelFile = "../ReceivingExcelFile.xlsx";
let sheetName = "Sheet1"
let workbook = XLSX.readFile(excelFile);
let ws = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];


// Overwrite worksheet
workbook.Sheets[sheetName] = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, excelFile);

// });

};



// post.js / routes 

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//controllers
const PostCtrl = require('../controllers/post');
//saving new posts to DB 
router.post('/',  PostCtrl.createPost);


//export
module.exports = router;


// app.js

//import 
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
//body parser
app.use(express.json());

//routes
const postRoutes = require('./routes/post');

//Cors 
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested- 
With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, 
DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
next();
});

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);

app.post('/storedReceivingObject', postRoutes);

module.exports = app;



// server.js 

const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');

const normalizePort = val => {
const port = parseInt(val, 10);

if (isNaN(port)) {
return val;
}
if (port >= 0) {
return port;
}
return false;
};
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

const errorHandler = error => {
if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
throw error;
}
const address = server.address();
const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 
'port: ' + port;
switch (error.code) {
case 'EACCES':
console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges.');
process.exit(1);
break;
case 'EADDRINUSE':
console.error(bind + ' is already in use.');
process.exit(1);
break;
default:
throw error;
}
};

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.on('error', errorHandler);
server.on('listening', () => {
const address = server.address();
const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 
'port ' + port;
console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
});

server.listen(port);
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. "doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description. What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? (Also check any server logs.) We also need the relevant code here in the question, as a [mcve]. Links can break, or the linked content can change (especially on github!), making the question useless for others with similar problems.

Comment: Hi Robert, I've updated the question now to contain the code.  I just thought it would be better to show the exact folder structure.  What I have here is simply what works for writing to an Excel file.  I didn't include the ways I tried to send the object because I tried loads of things, but I can get some of the most relevant ways, i just need to go through my files to get them.  And for the most part, I am sure they are very wrong anyway